# Create multiple Button with different text in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter

I was trying to implement some code to produce multiple buttons and at the same time writing different texts on them, for example from a dictionary, is it possible?

```
dict_words={1 : "hello",
            2 : "ciao"
           }
for i in range(8):
   for k,j in dict_words:
        tk.Button(top_frame, width=20, text=dict_words.values[j], padx=5, pady=5).pack()
```

I am not managing to do this, some help is highly appreciated.

Thank you,
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure what you're trying to iterate over using the range. Here's something that iterates over you dictionary, creating a button with the value item of each key-value-pair (kvp).

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
dict_words = {1 : "hello",
            2 : "ciao"
             }
for k,j in dict_words.items():
    b = Button(root, width=20, text=j, padx=5, pady=5)
    b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```